# How to create a DOMNode in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom, dom-node

The class [`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) doesn't provide a contructor and also no `static` methods like `createInstance()`. So, how to create an `DOMNode` instance?

Comment: You may actually want a [DOMElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php).

Comment: Exactly, you are right! I [confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846468/how-to-create-a-domnode-in-php/17846499?noredirect=1#comment26052423_17846499) these two things. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `DOMDocument`. It extends from DOMNode, has a constructor, and represents the rootnode of a document. Being a DOMNode, DOMDocument has methods for adding children. For instance, DOMDocument has a method [CreateElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php), which returns a DOMElement, which also inherits from DOMNode. All in all, it seems that DOMNode is just the base class and shouldn't be used directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think, my problem was, that I was confusing `DOM node` with `DOM element`.