# How to set name and value for a DOMNode in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom, dom-node

The class [`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) has attributes `nodeName` and `nodeValue`, but doesn't provide any setters for them. OK, `nodeValue` is public and can be accessed directly. But how to set the `readonly` `nodeName`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a DOMNode directly. Use a DOMElement. When you create a DOMElement (either directly, or through [DOMDocument.CreateElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php)), you can specify a name.

Comment: Btw, aren't you that guy from the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846468/how-to-create-a-domnode-in-php)? :-)

Comment: Yes, I am. )) Thank you for your answer! But, OK, if I create a `DOMElement`. How can I change its name?

Comment: I guess you don't. It's probably due to some implementation detail, but they didn't make the nodeName readOnly for nothing. In what circumstances do you want to add an element and then change its name?

Comment: E.g. when I don't know, what name the new element should have and create it with a dummy name first, in order to set it later correctly.

Comment: I think you cannot change it. You can however simulate renaming by creating a new element and move all properties and subelements to the new element. One Felix wrote a piece of code to do just that on PHP.net. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#111494